# Fast way to check whether number in list is in given range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries in the following way:

```
list1 = [{'some_id': 1, 'lower_range': 3, 'upper_range': 7},
         {'some_id': 2, 'lower_range': 8, 'upper_range': 12},
         {'some_id': 3, 'lower_range': 13, 'upper_range': 16}]
```

A second list contains some integers:

```
list2 = [{'value': 4, 'data': 'A'},
         {'value': 8, 'data': 'B'},
         {'value': 9, 'data': 'C'},
         {'value': 15, 'data': 'D'}]
```

I now want to join `'some_id'` and `'data'` such that `'value'` is between `'lower_range'` and `'upper_range'` in a new list. I.e., I want the output to be

```
list3 = [{'some_id': 1, 'data': 'A'},
         {'some_id': 2, 'data': 'B'},
         {'some_id': 2, 'data': 'C'},
         {'some_id': 3, 'data': 'D'}]
```

One way to do this would be

```
list3 = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if (j['value'] >= i['lower_range'] and
            j['value'] <= i['upper_range']):
            list3.append({'some_id': i['some_id'], 'data': j['data']})
```

However, this seems highly inefficient. Is there some faster way?

Comment: What should happen, when the ranges overlap in `list1`?

Comment: Preferably it would throw an error, because it should not be possible

Comment: list2 is correct? currently this is a list having a dictionary.

Comment: will everyone have exactly one match? or do zero/multiple matches are possible?

Comment: @Reut Sharabani: Multiple matches should not be possible. And most likely zero should not be possible either.

Comment: Are `list1` and `list2` pre-processed in any way? In other words, are there guaranteed properties of those data values? In particular, is `list1` sorted so the ranges are in increasing order without overlap, and is `list2` also sorted so the values of `value` are increasing? (`list2` could contain an ordered dictionary, for example.) If so, there is a simple, fast algorithm to do this. If not, you could sort those values first.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: They would not necessarily be sorted, but I could of course do so.

Comment: @set0gut1 You're right, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special premise that the ranges do not overlap.
So we can find a candidate by searching for an element with the maximum lower_bound that satisfies the condition.

Binary search can reduce complexity from `O(n*n)` to `O(n log n)`.
In python3, we can use bisect.

```
list1 = [{'some_id': 1, 'lower_range': 3, 'upper_range': 7},
         {'some_id': 2, 'lower_range': 8, 'upper_range': 12},
         {'some_id': 3, 'lower_range': 13, 'upper_range': 16}]

list2 = [{'value': 4, 'data': 'A'},
         {'value': 8, 'data': 'B'},
         {'value': 9, 'data': 'C'},
         {'value': 15, 'data': 'D'}]

list3 = []

list1.sort(key = lambda r: r['lower_range'])
lower_ranges = [r['lower_range'] for r in list1]

from bisect import bisect_right

for record in list2:
    position = bisect_right(lower_ranges, record['value']) - 1
    if (position < 0): continue
    candidate = list1[position]
    if (record['value'] <= candidate['upper_range']):
        list3.append({'some_id': candidate['some_id'], 'data': record['data']})

print(list3)
```

output (manual indented)

```
[{'some_id': 1, 'data': 'A'},
 {'some_id': 2, 'data': 'B'},
 {'some_id': 2, 'data': 'C'},
 {'some_id': 3, 'data': 'D'}]
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution, marginally faster than the answer of Reut Sharabani.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit verbose but should be more efficient (`O(nlogn)` < `O(n^2)`) due to sorting (you can also sort in-place with `list.sort`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from operator import itemgetter

list1 = [{'some_id': 1, 'lower_range': 3, 'upper_range': 7},
        {'some_id': 2, 'lower_range': 8, 'upper_range': 12},
        {'some_id': 3, 'lower_range': 13, 'upper_range': 16}]

list2 = [{'value': 4, 'data': 'A'},
        {'value': 8, 'data': 'B'},
        {'value': 9, 'data': 'C'},
        {'value': 15, 'data': 'D'}]

# sort before merging so we iterate less (O(nlogn))
list1 = sorted(list1, key=itemgetter('lower_range'))
list2 = sorted(list2, key=itemgetter('value'))


it1 = iter(list1)
it2 = iter(list2)

# merge lists that we know are sorted (simple merging algorithm - O(n))
try:
    curr_range = next(it1)
    curr_val = next(it2)
    list3 = []
    while True:
        rng = range(curr_range['lower_range'], curr_range['upper_range'] + 1)
        value = curr_val['value']
        if value in rng:
            # got a match, add it and check if there are more values
            list3.append({'some_id': curr_range['some_id'],
                          'data': curr_val['data']})
            curr_val = next(it2)
            continue
        if value < curr_range['lower_range']:
            # no match, skip to next value
            curr_val = next(it2)
            continue
        if value >= curr_range['upper_range']:
            # range too low for value, try next one
            curr_range = next(it1)
            continue
except StopIteration:
    pass
print(list3)
```

Gives:

```
[{'data': 'A', 'some_id': 1},
 {'data': 'B', 'some_id': 2},
 {'data': 'C', 'some_id': 2},
 {'data': 'D', 'some_id': 3}]
```

Comment: You're right! missed that in OP's code.

Comment: You could shorten the code quite a bit if you write it [like this](http://dpaste.com/0CMV249).

Comment: This code is around 50 times faster than what I did in the OP

Answer (score 2):

You could create a dict that maps values to ids like `{3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, ..., 8: 2, 9: 2, ...}`, which would let you find each dict's id in constant O(1) time:

```
# create a dict that maps values to ids
value_to_id_dict = {}
for dic in list1:
    id_ = dic['some_id']
    for value in range(dic['lower_range'], dic['upper_range']+1):
        value_to_id_dict[value] = id_

# look up each dict's id in the dict we just created
list3 = []
for dic in list2:
    new_dic = {'data': dic['data'],
               'some_id': value_to_id_dict[dic['value']]}
    list3.append(new_dic)

# result:
# [{'data': 'A', 'some_id': 1},
#  {'data': 'B', 'some_id': 2},
#  {'data': 'C', 'some_id': 2},
#  {'data': 'D', 'some_id': 3}]
```

Comment: Important to note that this would create ~100000 entries for `{'lower_range': 0, 'upper_range': 1000000}` ...

Comment: didn't see the +1 there :P added an approximate so we don't nitpick :D

Comment: This code is around 25 times faster than what I did in the OP